# USB not recharging anymore

Tags: samsung, usb

I have a Samsung Tablet 10 and so far it recharged when connected to my computers usb plug.

Suddenly i am not able to connect my device anymore.

With a recharger cable I am able to charge the device.

Any thoughts ot help ?

Comment: There are 4 wires in a USB. 2 Data-wires and the other 2 for charging. If you can charge but can't transfer the data or USB is not recognized, this means data wires are now broken.

Answer (score 0):

If you can still transfer data between the phone and the computer via the cable, the computer might have an issue with powering the USB port. Maybe you somehow exceeded a current limit.

If you can no longer transfer data, and you can using a different cable, then your cable is broken. I think this is the most likely case.